# How to avoid slow execution time in php when database has a lot of data

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My code is taking a lot of time to execute as my database has lots of data. Initially when there were 5000 rows it worked fine, but now my data has increased and it takes approximately 2 minutes to load. My PHP code is:

```
$result=$db->query("SELECT DateLastSaved,MDid,FileName FROM InitialLog");

$filesarray=array();
$datearray=array();

while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $tobestored=$row3['MDid']."||".$row3['FileName'];

    $key=array_search($tobestored,$filesarray);
    $date=$row3['DateLastSaved'];                


    if(!is_numeric($key))
    {
        $filesarray[]=$tobestored;
       $datearray[]=$date;
    }
    else
    {
        $aryear=date("Y",strtotime($datearray[$key]));
        $armonth=date("m",strtotime($datearray[$key]));
        $arday=date("d",strtotime($datearray[$key]));

        $pryear=date("Y",strtotime($date));
        $prmonth=date("m",strtotime($date));
        $prday=date("d",strtotime($date));

       if($aryear==$pryear && $armonth==$prmonth)
       {
           if($prday>$arday)
           {
               $datearray[$key]=$date;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Array is taking a lot of time in this code.

(From a comment). My purpose is to get all the file names of each MD as well as Date Last saved. If from the list, a specific file is repeated and is present in January, February and so on, I want the file from January only, that is the oldest month and also from that month I want the last in that month, that is if it exists on 1st Jan, 2nd jan, 30th jan, I would like to get the 30th Jan one.

Comment: Index your database, and avoid queries using LIKE if at all possible

Comment: `NOT LIKE '%Patient Names%'` You should create more targetable field for this table. May be another table like, `InitialLogPatients`.

Comment: Index can't to help here, because he makes fulltext search(not starting with).

Comment: Oh, is `Patient Names` constant string or list of patient names? If first, you can to add just another one field(for example, type) and manage it, while filter you logs. `WHERE type='Patient Names'`

Comment: Your last edit makes completely other question :(

Comment: Everybody is pointing towards NOT LIKE, although in my other code I am not using LIKE or NOT LIKE and still it is slow. So I need some other work aroung

Comment: What is inside your `$filesarray` array? It seems to be empty. [mcve]

Comment: @vp_arth initially it is empty but later file names are inserted in it

Comment: `array_search` with outer loop is O(n^2).

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you are trying to do in user-level terms; it's hard to guess by reading your code. The entire point of a DBMS like MySQL is to use `WHERE ` clauses in queries so you don't have to read the entire table to find the row you want.

Comment: @OllieJones I want to get all the results and then compare them. I am inserting them in array and then further reading them and performing my required task

Comment: @vp_arth pointed out correctly that you have chosen an O(n-squared) algorithm. That is, your method of comparison will take time proportional to the square of the number of rows in your table. That's bad because your speed deteriorates fast as you get more data.  I asked what you're trying to do in user level terms because I was hoping to suggest an algorithm that doesn't take n-squared time. If your requirement is to compare every row to every other row, and there's no way to improve on that, your code is pretty good and you're stuck with a slow program.  But, I doubt that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specification (presented in a comment on your question) is this:

- For each distinct value of `MDid` -- for each doctor -- ...
- Find the first month in which your table contains any row ...
- Then find the latest row in that first month, and ...
- Present that row in the result set.

*Pro tip:* try to formulate this kind of specification as clearly as possible before starting to write code. The hairier the specification, the more important it is to have clarity. This specification has hair.

Let's build this up as a MySQL query.  First, you need to find the first month each `MDid` appears. This subquery does that using [`LAST_DAY()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).  In this application, think of `LAST_DAY(date)` as meaning `MONTH_AND_YEAR_OF(date)`.

```
                      SELECT MDid, MIN(LAST_DAY(DateLastSaved)) FirstMonth
                        FROM InitialLog
                       GROUP BY MDid
```

This aggregating subquery yields one row per doctor, with the very last day of the first month in it.  (That's what `MIN(LAST_DAY(DateLastSaved))` does.)

*Pro tip:* many people find it helpful to test their subqueries in phpMyAdmin or some other command line SQL program.

Let us now use it in another subquery to find the latest date that occurs in that first month in the table.

```
           SELECT MAX(DateLastSaved) LastInMonth,
                  a.MDid
             FROM InitialLog a
             JOIN (
                           SELECT MDid, MIN(LAST_DAY(DateLastSaved)) FirstMonth
                             FROM InitialLog
                            GROUP BY MDid
                  ) b  ON a.MDid = b.MDid 
                      AND LAST_DAY(a.DateLastSaved) = b.FirstMonth
            GROUP BY a.MDid
```

Here we join the `InitialLog` table to the first subquery, using the `ON` clause to eliminate all the rows of `InitialLog` that aren't in the first month (that's what `LAST_DAY(a.DateLastSaved) = b.FirstMonth` does).

Cool. this subquery gives us the date in your specification for each doctor.  Finally, we have to go get the original row, containing the `FileName` as well as the other columns.  We already know the `MDid` and the `DateLastSaved`.

This is the final query.

```
SELECT orig.DateLastSaved, orig.MDid, orig.FileName
  FROM InitialLog orig
  JOIN (  /* that subquery */
       ) datechoice ON orig.MDid = datechoice.MDid
                   AND orig.DateLastSaved = datechoice.LastInMonth
 ORDER BY orig.MDid /* or whatever order you want */
```

This gives one row per MDid. It uses the DBMS to implement your specification, rather than looking at all the rows of your table. If your table has an index on `(MDid, DateLastSaved)` this query will probably scale up very well when you have tens of thousands of doctors and decades of data in your table.

Putting it all together, your php program is this. Now you may be able to guess why it's called **Structured** Query language.

```
$docs_first_monthend_bill_query = <<<ENDQUERY
SELECT orig.DateLastSaved, orig.MDid, orig.FileName
  FROM InitialLog orig
  JOIN (  
           SELECT MAX(DateLastSaved) LastInMonth,
                  a.MDid
             FROM InitialLog a
             JOIN (
                           SELECT MDid, MIN(LAST_DAY(DateLastSaved)) FirstMonth
                             FROM InitialLog
                            GROUP BY MDid
                  ) b  ON a.MDid = b.MDid 
                      AND LAST_DAY(a.DateLastSaved) = b.FirstMonth
            GROUP BY a.MDid
       ) datechoice ON orig.MDid = datechoice.MDid
                   AND orig.DateLastSaved = datechoice.LastInMonth
 ORDER BY orig.MDid /* or whatever order you want */
ENDQUERY;

$result=$db->query($docs_first_monthend_bill_query);
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    /* process the interesting rows */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I guess I failed in explaining it to you well. In your case it is returning one file per MD. This is not what I want. All File names would be considered but if one file is repeated in every month or repeated in the same month, then I want that file to be of the first month and the last date. All file names have to be considered

Comment: But your query has helped me understand to do whatever I want to and I will be using it. Thank you so much for helping. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `HashMap`.
In php terms it is simple associative array.

```
$key=$row3['MDid']."||".$row3['FileName'];
$date=$row3['DateLastSaved'];                

if(!isset($datearray[$key]))
{
   $datearray[$key]=$date;
}
else
{
...
}
```

It has constant key search time and should be excellent for task you tried to solve.

Comment: Thanks. It's not executing that slowly now. There is improvement

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the page loading time by using LIMIT in query and fetch result with pagination. So the all records will not come in a single result set but that can be possible via paging

```
SELECT DateLastSaved,MDid,FileName FROM InitialLog WHERE FileName NOT LIKE '%Patient Names%' LIMIT $offset $perpage
```

Here `$offset` is the index number of your results (page_number * $perpage) and `$perpage` is the how much rows you want to fetch in a single query.

Comment: It just increase total execution time(but can decrease memory requirements), if you still need to process all data.

Answer (score 0):

On first thought i would say you are trying to get the most recent 'DateLastSaved' for each 'MDid' and 'FileName' combination.

If so, i would simply alter the SQL to

```
SELECT concat(MDid, FileName) tobestored, 
       max(DateLastSaved) maxDateLastSaved
FROM InitialLog 
GROUP BY 1
```

This query would return only one row per 'MDid' and 'FileName' combination containing the combined value and the most recent date.

No more need to loop through all fetched records to search arraykeys or compare dates.

The only thing that i am not sure about is this part

```
if($aryear==$pryear && $armonth==$prmonth) {
  if($prday>$arday) {
    $datearray[$key]=$date;
  }
}
```

Looks like you want to keep the older 'DateLastSaved' if it is from a previous month or year.
If this applies, my change to your query does not give your desired data.

Comment: I want oldest file but that should be the last one in the month if it is repeated, I don't need the latest